# React Native - cameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll isn't saving my video

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to save a video to my camera roll and im getting this error:

invariant violation: the second argument to saveToCameraRoll must be 'photo' or 'video' or 'audio' you passed video.

Here is my save/record function:

```
Record = async () => {
    if (this.camera) {
      const options = {maxDuration: 5};
      const data = await this.camera.recordAsync(options);
      console.log(data.uri);
      CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll(data.uri, ['video']);
    }
```

I've tried removing the brackets and it still didn't resolve the warning, or save the video to my camera roll.

Answer (score 0):

Same me, but when checklog with Xcode, it show "libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb)" error and crash my App :(